# How do I regenerate the template contents after outside modification of objects used in a dom-repeat template?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

How do I regenerate the template after outside modification of objects used for dom_repeat template?

I have a files list created with a paper-item list, drawn from an array with file objects.

Now when I update the path on the file object, the list does not update the display value. While all other fields showing the same file are updated.

Am I missing something?

The template code used:

```
        <paper-menu attr-for-selected="value" selected="{{currentFile}}">
            <template id="filesList" is="dom-repeat" items="{{files}}">
                <paper-item value="{{item}}">
                    <div>{{item.path}}</div>
                    <paper-icon-button icon="fa:pencil" on-tap="propertiesAction"></paper-icon-button>
                </paper-item>
            </template>
        </paper-menu>
```

The object properties:

```
        files: {
            type: Object,
            value: [],
            notify: true,
            observer: 'filesChanged'
        },
        currentFile: {
            type: Object,
            notify: true
        },
```

After selecting a file in the list, the currentfile displays the correct values, but the file list still shows the old path.

**Edit:**
The template below is a dialog that can change the path of the file.

```
<template>
    <editor-dialog
        id="inputDialog"
        style="z-index: 14"
        title="{{title}}">
        <paper-input id="fileName" name="filename" label="Filename" value="{{file.path}}"></paper-input>
        <paper-button id="saveButton">Save</paper-button>
        <!--paper-input name="mode" value="false"></paper-input-->
    </editor-dialog>
</template>
```

```
Polymer({
    is:'editor-file-properties',
    properties: {
        file: {
            type: Object,
            value: {},
            notify: true
        },
        title: {
            type: String,
            value: function () {
                return this.file ? 'Edit file properties' : 'New file';
            }
        }
    },
    listeners: {
        'saveButton.tap': 'saveFile'
    },
    saveFile: function() {
        var sFileName = this.$.fileName.value;
        if (sFileName == "")
            return;

        if (!this.file)
        {
            var obj = this;
            FileModel.create(sFileName, function (file) {
                obj.file = file;
            });
        }
        this.notifyPath('file.path', this.file.path);
        this.$.inputDialog.close();
    },
```

Before I open the dialog I was setting the file to currentFile or

```
this.$.fileDialog.file = this.currentFile;
```

I have now changed this to use a binding. This code is just below the dom-repeat template

```
<editor-file-properties id="fileDialog" file="{{currentFile}}"></editor-file-properties>
```

Now the titlebar of the currentFile gets updated immediately when I am typing, but still the files list does not directly update the current file. Is there any manual way of binding two elements?

Comment: Can you post the code where you update file object.

Comment: I have updated the question with how I modify the file.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using `array-selector`. I don't think `paper-menu` uses it. Below is the definition from developer guide. You can read more about it https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#array-selector

> Keeping structured data in sync requires that Polymer understand the
>   path associations of data being bound. The array-selector element
>   ensures path linkage when selecting specific items from an array. The
>   array selector supports either single or multiple selection.

1. You need to include an array selector in your code

   ```
   <array-selector id="selector" items="{{files}}" selected="{{selectedFile}}"></array-selector>
   ```
2. You need to include `iron-select` event listener to your `paper-menu`

   ```
   <paper-menu selected="{{selectedIndex}}" on-iron-select="arraySelect">
   ```
3. In the `arraySelect` function, select the item using array-selector.

   ```
   arraySelect: function (e) {
     var item = this.$.filesList.itemForElement(e.explicitOriginalTarget);
     this.$.selector.select(item);
   }
   ```
4. Pass this selected item to the other elements which updates it.

   ```
   <editor-file-properties id="fileDialog" file="{{selectedFile}}"></editor-file-properties>
   ```

Working plunker: http://embed.plnkr.co/qd0BNMbeAyXSkknaA1tP/preview

Comment: This seems complicated for expecting 2 way binding, what if I want a random item from the list or multiple items get updated by another user and get downloaded by the server which updates the names, why does the list not regenerate when an item on the list changes specified properties

Comment: I just added 5 lines of code to your current code. Anyway, if you make changes to the array compliant to https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#array-binding, then the list will get updated automatically.

Comment: Also, as per the defintion, array-selector allows multiple selection, it also allows you to work on toggle mode. i.e. if you select same item twice, it will be deselected.

Comment: The plunker you have posted does not change the selected state's name when I click the update name button.

<paper-menu attr-for-selected="value" selected="{{currentFile}}">

Does work to select the file I want to use(Everything reacts to the currentfile being set with binding, my issue is that the dom-repeat template does not seem to update its values when I modify one of the items in that list. (Which I share the same way I do the currentFile)

Comment: Also when I modify currentFile.path in with the input in the dialog, all the otther places in the window get updated, except for the dom-repeat list.